# Generate Multiple Docs from a Template

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation, google-docs, doc

Scenario:
- I have a doc (google doc or microsoft word) template
- The doc has 3 lines: Name, Age, Address
- The rest of the doc: header and footer

Do you know a software or a way so i can semi-automatically produce several docs using the template but with different Name, Age, Address, and name the docs while i'm at it?

Comment: Alexey is right - this is well known as mail merge.  To narrow down the options, do you have a preferred environment / programming language?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are asking about is called Mail Merge. In Ms Word document (template) you should insert special fields - merge fields and then execute mail merge. For example you can use Aspose.Words (there is .NET, Java and C++ versions) to achieve this.
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/About+Mail+Merge

Also there is Aspose.Words Cloud, that has this feature too
https://docs.aspose.cloud/display/wordscloud/Working+with+Mail+Merge

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate multiple documents using template document by just replacing the fields such as Name, Age or Address using [Zoho Writer](https://www.zoho.com/writer/).

Steps:

1. Create template document
2. Insert mail merge fields for dynamic content (Fields such as Name, Age, Address)
3. Upload you data source it can be csv or sheet format
4. You can configure output options too. Such as export as merge and generate PDF or merge and send or merge and save as individual documents.

Source:
https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/mail-merge.html